# NiFi (1.12.1) ConvertRecord processor with ParquetReader throws NullPointerException

Tags: apache-nifi, parquet

**Update:** After some analysis I saw NIFI JIRA regarding this issue. [Issue-1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7998) [Issue-2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7817). Looks like NiFi fixed this issue in **1.13.0** version.

I have created a flow to read parquet file and convert the file into JSON format. Flow is getting failed in Convert Record Processor.

Below is the flow, (Red box of convert record shows "**will route to failure: Name is null**")

[image]

Failure queue of ConvertRecord processor is below,
[image]

Here's the ParquetReader controller service,
[image]

I took the input file from [GitHub Kylo Sample Data](https://github.com/Teradata/kylo/blob/master/samples/sample-data/parquet/userdata1.parquet)

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: does your record reader schema defined `Name` as allow not null?

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde Added  parquet record reader controller service screenshot